# Building Spark scala project using Bazel

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bazel

I want to build a Spark with Scala project using Bazel which has been built using SBT and executed successfully. This is how my build.sbt looks like

```
name := "ScalaWithSpark"  version := "0.1"  scalaVersion := "2.11.11"  
//libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.6.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0"
```

Basically I have gone through all the concepts of Bazel but still its like dots scattered for me I need help in connecting the dots Tq

Comment: What have you tried? What are you stuck with?

Comment: You’re welcome to come to our Gitter “Bazel with Scala” and ask questions there